# CakePHP delete records older than 5 days

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Basically, I want to do this in CakePHP:

```
delete from myTable as mytable where datediff(now(), mytable.date) > 5
```

And I don't know how to do it with the `$this->Model->delete()` function?

Comment: By reading the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall

Comment: @Cruzer you need to supply a condition array. See answers below.

Comment: You should try reading the documentaiton in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `deleteAll`:

```
$this->Model->deleteAll(array(
    'datediff(now(), Model.date) > 5'
)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to preform a custom query is use Model::query method. It's not the recommend way, but it seems like you want a quick/dirty answer.

```
$this->MyModel->query("delete from myTable as mytable where datediff(now(), 
                        mytable.date) > 5");
```

If you do this method make sure you escape the query string to prevent SQLi attacks.

Recommended way:

```
Use Model::deleteAll(mixed $conditions, $cascade = true, $callbacks = false)

$conditions = array('datediff(now(), Model.date) > 5');
$this->MyModel->deleteAll($conditions,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.x you should use this:

```
// In a controller or table method.
$time = \Cake\I18n\Time::now();
$time->modify('-5 days');
$query = $this->Model->deleteAll(['Model.date <=' => $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```